# Who is "focker" and why does he own my schema?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres DB deployment in Compose.io, and I am using the standard "compose" db for my app.  I would like to wipe out the current DB contents so that I can recreate the DB with a new schema.  I have read that the best way to do this is with "drop schema public cascade", but when I try to do this on my db I get

```
ERROR:  must be owner of schema public
```

It turns out that the schema is not owned by `admin` (the user that compose provides for psql access), but by a user named `focker`.

```
compose=> \dn
 List of schemas
  Name  | Owner  
--------+--------
 public | focker
(1 row)
```

I tried changing the schema owner but that fails with the same error as above.

Why is my db set up this way?  Is there any way I can change it so that the admin user can wipe out a db?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, I can only answer the question in the title.

Here's an excerpt [from an article on Compose.io](https://www.compose.io/articles/rethinkdb-and-compose-talk-databases-and-hosting/) that might shed some light on your question:

> As LXC {*Linux containers*} doesn't have a nice command line API, Compose has developed its own internal tool. As Docker started as a nice command line for LXC, Kurt noted that Compose's tools were now named, tongue firmly in cheek, Focker. **Focker** is where all the tools are bundled up and, unlike Docker which focuses on packaging, it concentrates on the resource allocation and managment. The container instances are then connected via [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/) which allows each customer to have their own private VLAN for their database.

Bottom line - "focker" represents the command line API "user" of Compose.io.

---

In [yet another article](https://www.compose.io/articles/compose-backups-going-local/), we can see the following:

> ```
> [snapshot] more README
>
> This snapshot is meant to be run with the same minor version  
> of Postgresql, which is postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5.
>
> To startup a Postgresql environment with this snapshot, run:  
> `postgres -D conf`
>
> You can then connect to the db by running: `psql postgres -U focker`
> ```
>
> ...

My best bet would be trying: `psql postgres -U focker`

Comment: +1. Just for the `psql postgres` **`-U focker`**